# IE is not seeing body tag. works fine in chrome

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>USLI Intranet</title>
<script src="Scripts/swfobject_modified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="Style_sheets/front_menu_new.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="slider_omg/js/swfobject_modified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Tabbed jQuery slideshow</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="slider_omg/css/slideshow.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="slider_omg/js/jquery.cycle.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="slider_omg/js/slideshow.js"></script>



<link href="benefitsnew/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}
.style2 {font-size: 12px}
.style5 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #999999;
}
.style6 {color: #999999}

a {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    /*font-size: 12px;*/
    color: #003698;
}
a:visited {
    color: #003698;
}
a:hover {
    color: #E06B00;
}
.active{
    background-color: #004499;
    }

#leftThird{
    float:left;
    width:570px; 

    }
#rightThird{
    float:right;
    width:131px;
    position:relative;
    text-align:left;    
    }



</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
  <div id="header">
    <div class="left" ><a href = "index.htm"><img src="Pics/LOGO-AND-TAGLINE.gif" border = "0"/></a></div>
    <div class="right">
      <p> 1190 Devon Park Drive • Wayne, PA 19087<br />
        888-523-5545 </p>
      <form class="zoom_searchform" action="http://intranet.usli.com/Search2/search.asp" method="get">
        <input type="text" maxlength="255" class="zoom_searchbox" size="18" name="zoom_query" value="Search our Site"  onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search Our Site';}"onFocus="this.value='';" />
        <input type="submit" class="button" name="search" value="Find" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="menu">
    <ul id="oldtopmenu">
      <li><a href="../5CommunityGoals/5CommunityGoals.htm">Five Community<br />
        Goals</a></li>
      <li><a href="../UnderwritingTools/UnderwritingTools.htm">Underwriting<br />
        Tools</a></li>
      <li><a href="../PersonalDevelopment/pdc2.htm">Personal<br />
        Development Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="../Company Story/CompanyStory.htm">Company<br />
        Story</a></li>
      <li><a href="../LeadershipwithHeart/LeadershipwithHeart.htm">Leadership<br />
        with Heart</a></li>
      <li><a href="../BusinessCodeEthics/BusinessCodeEthics.htm">Business Code<br />
        &amp; Ethics</a></li>
      <li><a href="../BranchOffices/Branch-Offices.html">Branch<br />
        Offices</a></li>
      <li ><a href="../CommunityTeams/CommunityTeams_landing_page.html">Community<br />
        Teams</a></li>
      <li><a href="../Forms/ServiceRequestForms.htm" style="padding:5px 16px;">Service<br />
        Request Forms</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="oldbotmenu">
      <li><a class=" active "  href="../index.htm">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.usli.com" target="_blank">Public Website</a></li>
      <li class="double-line "><a  href="../EmergencyResponse/EmergencyResponse.htm">Emergency Response /<br />
        Staffing Plan</a></li>
      <li class="double-line"><a href="../CareerOpportunities/CareerOpportunities.htm">Career<br />
        Opportunities</a></li>
      <li class="double-line"><a href="../PhoneList.htm">Community Mtg.<br />
        Presentation</a></li>
      <li class="double-line"><a href="../StaffLocator/StaffLocator_Pictures.htm">Phone List /<br />
        People Search</a></li>
      <li><a href="../Reflection/InLovingMemory.htm">Remembrance</a></li>
      <li><a href="../ResourcesPages/Resources.htm" style="padding:0 17px;">Resources</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    <div id="leftThird" >
      <!--ZOOMSEARCH-->
      <!--<div class="webexlink">
 <p style="background-image: url(./Pics/frontpage/uslipinkbanner.jpg); width:445px; height:99px; padding-left: 75px; padding-top:10px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; color: #FFFFFF; margin-left:0px;">Support Breast Cancer Awareness. <a href="http://www.usli.com/pink" target="_blank">Learn More >></a></p></div>-->
      <p>
        <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="505" height="290" id="FlashID" title="USLI slideshow">
          <param name="movie" value="ImageRotator.swf">
          <param name="quality" value="high">
          <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
          <param name="swfversion" value="8.0.35.0">
          <!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don&rsquo;t want users to see the prompt. -->
          <param name="expressinstall" value="../Scripts/expressInstall.swf">
          <!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
          <!--[if !IE]>-->
          <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="ImageRotator.swf" width="505" height="290">
            <!--<![endif]-->
            <param name="quality" value="high">
            <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
            <param name="swfversion" value="8.0.35.0">
            <param name="expressinstall" value="../Scripts/expressInstall.swf">
            <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
            <div>
              <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
              <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" width="112" height="33" /></a></p>
            </div>
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
          </object>
          <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>
        <br>
      </p>
      <p><a href="http://www.usli.com/community"><img src="Pics/frontpage/communityportal.jpg" alt="" name="" width="520" height="115" usemap="#Map" border="0">
        <map name="Map">
          <area shape="rect" coords="266,2,519,112" href="http://www.usli.com/community" target="_blank">
          <area shape="rect" coords="5,2,258,112" href="http://www.usli.com/community/docs/CourseCatalogforFamilies_2014.pdf" target="_blank">
        </map>
      </a> </p>
      <div class="pdc">Community Updates</div>
      <div id="slideshow">
        <div class="slides">
          <ul>
            <li id="slide-one">
              <h2 id="headline_new">Bring Your Benefits Home!<a href="benefitsnew/benefitshome.html" target="_self"><img src="slider_omg/images/slide_image_benefits.png" width="200" height="163" border="0" class="new_slider_image"></a><br>
              </h2>
              <p class="inside_text">Did you know you can access your benefit information and much more from home? Visit <a href="http://www.usli.com/community">www.usli.com/community &gt;&gt;</a><br>
                <br>
                You can also <a href="http://intranet.usli.com/USLIScheduler/Home/Classes">sign up</a> for any of the classes in the &quot;Benefit Workshop Series&quot; to learn<br>
                more about what is available to you through our benefits. <br>
                <br>
                <br>
              </p>
            </li>
            <li id="slide-two">
              <h2 id="headline_new">Security Awareness<a href="NewsEvents/Facilities.html"><img src="slider_omg/images/slide_image_facilities.png" width="200" height="162" border="0" class="new_slider_image"></a><br>
              </h2>
              <p class="inside_text"><span class="intranet_font">Remember that we can make a difference when it comes to keeping USLI safe. Follow <a href="PersonalDevelopment/Facilities/SecurityAwareness.html">these guidelines</a> to ensure your safety.<br>
                <br>
                <a href="PersonalDevelopment/Facilities/Surviving_a_Shooting.html">View the &quot;Surviving a Shooting&quot; video</a> as well to learn about three things you can do to make a difference. </span><br>
              </p>
            </li>
            <li id="slide-three">
              <h2 id="headline_new">Snap to It!<a href="NewsEvents/GraphicsandCommunications.html"><img src="slider_omg/images/slide_image_graphics.png" width="193" height="162" border="0" class="new_slider_image"></a><br>
              </h2>
              <p class="body_font"> If you’ve been meaning to hit the refresh button on your intranet photo or even better, take a more professional photo to improve your LinkedIn account, you’re in luck! Join us monthly for a quick private session. <a href="https://usli.wufoo.com/forms/r1rlr4dc1xpwssz/" target="_blank">Register &gt;&gt;</a><br>
              </p>
              <p><a href="PDFs/DApp_Flyer.pdf" target="_blank"></a><br>
              </p>
            </li>
            <li id="slide-four">
              <h2 id="headline_new"><strong>People's College for your<a href="NewsEvents/PeoplesCollege.htm"><img src="slider_omg/images/slide_image_pdc.png" width="200" height="164" border="0" class="new_slider_image"></a><br>
                family! </strong></h2>
              <p> <span class="body_font">Our classes are open to family members!<br>
                Tell your family members to <a href="http://www.usli.com/community/index.html#page_6/">register here &gt;&gt;</a><br>
                <br>
                <a href="NewsEvents/PeoplesCollege.htm">May course schedule is here! &gt;&gt;</a></span><br />
              </p>
            </li>
            <li id="slide-five">
              <h2 id="headline_new">It's May in Slainte!<a href="http://slainte.usli.com"><img src="slider_omg/images/slide_image_slainte.png" width="210" height="162" border="0"class="new_slider_image"></a><br>
              </h2>
              <p><span class="body_font"><strong><a href="PDFs/May2014Calendar.pdf">Check out the May calendar!</a></strong><br>
                Did you know you can get $150 back through the Healthy Lifestyles reimbursement? <a href="benefitsnew/healthy_lifestyles_ibx.pdf">Learn more about this opportunity!</a></span><br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br />
              </p>
            </li>
            <li id="slide-six">
              <h2 class="inside_text" id="headline_new"><strong>Join the USLI Helping Hands<strong><strong><a href="NewsEvents/CommunitySpirit.htm"><img src="slider_omg/images/slide_image_spirit.png" width="193" height="162" border="0" class="new_slider_image"></a></strong></strong><br>
                Committee<br>
              </strong></h2>
              <p> <span class="body_font">Our community stands behind those in need and lends a helping hand in many ways. <br>
                <a href="NewsEvents/CommunitySpirit.htm"><strong>Find Out More &gt;&gt;</strong></a></span><br>
                <br>
                <a href="PersonalDevelopment/CommunitySpirit/PaintingLaSalleAcademy/index.html" target="_blank"><br>
                </a><br>
                <br>
              </p>
              <br>
              <br />
            </li>
            <!--     <li id="slide-seven">
          <h2 id="headline_new">Customer Conferences: Help<br>
            Needed for 2014<a href="http://corporateevents.usli.com/" target="_blank"><img src="slider_omg/images/slide_image_corporateevents.png" width="198" height="162" border="0"class="new_slider_image"></a><br>
          </h2>
          <p> <span class="body_font">If you would be interested in greeting customers the morning of the conference or being a driver (picking up/dropping off at Applebrook, the airport, train station, etc.) for 2014, please contact Caitlyn (x2432) or Laurel (x2188). <a href="http://corporateevents.usli.com/">Read our blog. &gt;&gt;</a></span> <br />
          </p>
        </li>-->
          </ul>
        </div>
        <ul class="slides-nav">
          <li class="on"><a href="#slide-one">Benefits<br>
            <br>
          </a></li>
          <li><a href="#slide-two">Facilities<br>
            <br>
          </a></li>
          <li> <a href="#slide-three">Graphics &amp;<br>
            Social Media</a> </li>
          <li><a href="#slide-four">People's<br>
            College <br>
          </a></li>
          <li><a href="#slide-five">Slainte<br>
            <br>
          </a></li>
          <li><a href="#slide-six">CommunitySpirit / <br>
            Reception <br>
          </a></li>
          <!-- <li>
        <a href="#slide-seven">Corporate<br>
        Events</a></li>-->
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id = "rightThird">
      <div class="japan"><a href="http://intranet.usli.com:2012/StaffLocator/"> People<br>
        Locator </a> </div>
      <div class="rollover"><a href="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=uslievents@gmail.com&ctz=America/New_York" target="_blank">USLI Events<br>
        Calendar</a> </div>
      <div class="menu"> <a href="Dearcadh.htm">Today's Cafe<br>
        Selection </a> </div>
      <div class="id"> <a href="http://intranet.usli.com/HelpDesk">Service <br>
        Request<br>
      </a> </div>
      <div class="meeting"> <a href="http://intranet.usli.com/Scheduler/SchedulerHome.aspx">Class<br>
        Registration</a> </div>
      <div class="healthwellness"></div>
      <!--<div class="nothingbutnets"><a href="http://www.usli.com/nets" target="_blank"></a>
  </div>-->
      <!--  <div class="corpevents"><a href="http://corporateevents.usli.com" target="_blank"></a></div>-->
      <div class="oped"> <a href="http://successfulstudents.usli.com/" target="_blank" class="oped">Successful<br>
        Student Blog</a></div>
      <div class="news"> <a href="http://newsletter.usli.com" target="_blank">Customer<br>
        Newsletter</a> </div>
      <div class="spanishword"> <a href="PDFs/Spanishwordoftheweek.pdf" target="_blank">Spanish Word <br>
        of the Week</a> </div>
      <div class="care2wear"> <a href="CARE2/Care2WearGearEntrance.html" target="_blank">CARE2WEAR<br>
        GEAR </a> </div>
      <div class="julia"> <a href="PersonalDevelopment/Slainte/fitness-schedule/slaintegroupfitnessschedulewinter-1-2014.pdf" target="_blank"> Slainte Fitness Schedule</a> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<table width="750" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="93">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="Layer7" ></div>
<div id="Layer8" ></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
swfobject.registerObject("FlashID");
//-->
  </script>
<br>
<script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
try {
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-8410742-9");
pageTracker._trackPageview();
} catch(err) {}</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is the html for my webpage and it works fine in chrome. However in IE it does not show anything at all. Below is the html code that IE spits out in it's developer tools.**

```
<!-- saved from url=(0044)file://\\intranetdev1\intranet\indexNew.html -->
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<!-- Generated by F12 developer tools. This might not be an accurate representation of the original source file -->
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>USLI Intranet</TITLE>
<META content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv=Content-Type>
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="Scripts/swfobject_modified.js"></SCRIPT>
<LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="Style_sheets/front_menu_new.css">
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="slider_omg/js/swfobject_modified.js"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT id=__ie_ondomload defer src="//:"></SCRIPT>
<LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="slider_omg/css/slideshow.css" media=screen>
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="slider_omg/js/jquery.cycle.js"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="slider_omg/js/slideshow.js"></SCRIPT>
<LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="benefitsnew/main.css">
<STYLE type=text/css>.style1 {
    FONT-FAMILY: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}
.style2 {
    FONT-SIZE: 12px
}
.style5 {
    FONT-SIZE: 10px; FONT-FAMILY: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; COLOR: #999999
}
.style6 {
    COLOR: #999999
}
A {
    FONT-FAMILY: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; COLOR: #003698
}
A:visited {
    COLOR: #003698
}
A:hover {
    COLOR: #e06b00
}
.active {
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: #004499
}
#leftThird {
    FLOAT: left; WIDTH: 570px
}
#rightThird {
    POSITION: relative; FLOAT: right; TEXT-ALIGN: left; WIDTH: 131px
}
UNKNOWN {

}
UNKNOWN {

}
UNKNOWN {

}
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY class=js></BODY></HTML>
```

I am not sure why it automatically closes the body tag without the rest of the content. I also do not know where the class="js" is coming from. I have made sure that div tags are all lined up and shouldn't be causing the problem. I believe all tags having closing tags. I can provide links to all source files if needed. Just wondering if anybody has come across this themselves.

Thanks!

Comment: You opened `<!--` in your style tag, but never closed it, effectively commenting out your entire document.

Comment: try to change <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> to <!DOCTYPE HTML>

Comment: as @NiettheDarkAbsol says. check line ~20, where you are opening that tag and never closing it.

Comment: @kirie Validate your code: http://validator.w3.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further review of what IE is doing to your document, I'm confident that this is in fact the answer.

You have the massively outdated practice of "commenting out" your stylesheet so that older browsers ignore it. But really, no browser needs that any more.

But the point is, you're starting an HTML comment, but you forgot to end it. This is effectively commenting out your entire document. Chrome is being "clever" and fixing the issue for you, but Internet Explorer is being pedantic and correct by refusing the rest of the content.

I would suggest just removing the `<!--` from your `<style>` element. As I said, it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, this is a simple way, to find what's going on with your html, when something like this happens.

Go to http://validator.w3.org and select validate by URI, file upload or direct input. Click check!

Now, you should find the errors and a small description explaining what's going on!

In this particular case you've got at least  22 Errors and 25 warning(s).

But the main reason why you're not able to see BODY is because you left

```
<!-- on line 21 just after the style declaration
```

and never closed it.`